# Subscribe is called twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angular5

I'm trying to create a form to submit the details but when I subscribe the service, the subscription is done twice. First with null data and second with actual data.

Component.ts

```
addBook() {
    this.errorMessage = null;
    this.fireService.getBook(this.bookDetails.isbn).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('subscribe called');
      if (null != data) {
        this.dbox.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
          data: { title: 'Error', content: 'Book is already present in Library. Select Edit book to modify the details', button: false }
        });
        this.errorMessage = 'Book is already present in Library. Select Edit book to modify the details';
      } else {
        this.fireService.addBook(this.bookDetails);
        this.dbox.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
          data: { title: 'Success', content: 'Book has been Added to Database', button: false }
        });
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/add-book');
      }
    });
  }
```

Service.ts

```
getBook(id) {
  console.log('called firebase get book');
  return this.db.doc(`/books/${id}`).valueChanges();
}
```

Below is the image from the console of chrome. This shows that the subscription is called twice but not the firebase service.

[Chrome console logs: Image please click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZk2L.png)

chrome console logs

```
called firebase get book
subscribe called
subscribe called
```

Please help

Comment: try `this.fireService.getBook(this.bookDetails.isbn).pipe(filter(data => !!data)).subscribe(...)`

Comment: @ChauTran Tried your suggestions and i got the error saying The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.

Comment: Probably because I was using the `pipable methods`. Sorry, forgot to ask what version of angular/rxjs you're running. Run `.filter(data => !!data)` should behave the same way as well ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because the observable returned by getBooks emits a new value when the Books collection changes. The first time there is no book with the same isbn so data is null. Then you add one book and so the **same** observable fires again, this time with the book you just added

If you only want to get data once,
you can use take to only subscribe once.

```
this.fireService.getBook(this.bookDetails.isbn).take(1).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('subscribe called');
```

Comment: by this way (using take or first) observer completes and he won't get any more data

Comment: Tried that it says Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>

Comment: @RezaRahmati that's true but the way it is coded I assume that he calls addBook whenever he clicks a  button. That observable is not used to display a real time list

Comment: yes @David i call that function on click of a button

Comment: @Abhijith try importing the take operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Comment: @Abhijith I mentioned how to import `take` and you said it's not working and then David said same thing and you mention it's working!!!

Comment: I imported `import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';` which didn't work but when i used `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';` it worked. Strange but thats what happened. @RezaRahmati

Comment: @Abhijith btw if you see my edit on this answer I was mentioning import it like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'`, nvm friend

Answer (score 4):

like Chau Tran said, you can filter to get a valid response. If you haven't already, I'd add in a way to unsubscribe. In the code below `this.alive` is a field that is true, and turned false in the OnDestory life hook.

```
this.fireService.getBook(this.bookDetails.isbn)
.takeWhile(() => this.alive)
.filter(data => !!data)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: there is another way to cancel it by using new Subject. Here is the link.https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-best-practices-7f559d811514

Answer (score 1):

use pipe(take(1))

```
this.fireService.getBook(this.bookDetails.isbn).pipe(take(1)).
subscribe(data => {     console.log('subscribe called');
```

Answer (score 0):

With in the function `addBook` you are calling the subscription. Each time you call the function `addBook` you are making a subscription call, Avoid using subscription in such functions. Make sure to subscribe only in `onInit()`, so that it checks whenever you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and the issue was that the subscription was set twice, the function which subscribes the observer was called in `ngOnChanges` and `ngOnChanges` was called twice accidentally. Fixing `ngOnChanges` called twice fixed this issue as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).